# Inserting a CSV file into PostgreSQL table using bash script

Tags: bash, postgresql, shell, csv, insert

I'm trying to insert a CSV file into a PSQL table using a bash script. My first aim is parsing the CSV file then insert the datas, row by row. COPY command is not convenient for me. I've used the following script but it doesn't worked.

Edit: I didn't create the table by the way. Should I?

```
#!/bin/sh             
    while IFS=, read col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 col6 col7 col8 col9 col10 col11 col12
    do
        echo "INSERT INTO table_name ("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l") VALUES ('$col1','$col2','$col3','$col4','$col5','$col6','$col7','$col8','$col9','$col10','$col11','$col12');"
    done < ppr.csv | sudo psql -U pg_user -d test;
```

Comment: Could you provide more informations about your problem ? You say "It does not work", so what happen when it does not work ? Do you have any errors ?

Comment: ERROR:  relation "table_name" does not exist at character 13
LINE 1: INSERT INTO table_name (a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l) VALUES ..

Comment: Try using single quotes for the field names or escaping the double ones.

Comment: @Poshi - ERROR:  syntax error at or near "'a'" at character 18 after single quotes.

Comment: You should escape inner double quotation symbols.

Comment: You have to create the table, but that is your smallest problem. Correctly parsing CSV with bash is very tricky at least. Don't try it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should escape inner double quotation marks :

```
#!/bin/sh             
while IFS=, read col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 col6 col7 col8 col9 col10 col11 col12
do
    echo "INSERT INTO table_name (\"a\", \"b\", \"c\", \"d\", \"e\", \"f\", \"g\", \"h\", \"i\", \"j\", \"k\", \"l\") VALUES ('$col1','$col2','$col3','$col4','$col5','$col6','$col7','$col8','$col9','$col10','$col11','$col12');"
done < ppr.csv | sudo psql -U pg_user -d test;
```

Comment: ERROR:  relation "table_name" does not exist
LINE 1: INSERT INTO table_name. Should I create the table and columns first or ?

Comment: @Bertug Yes you should

Comment: Your solution won't work if any of the values contain a single quote. Also, that does not account for quoted fields.

Answer (score 1):

Don't try to parse CSV with bash, that would be quite hard to get right.

You should use [file_fdw](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/file-fdw.html) to define a foreign table in the database. That allows you to access the data from the database without actually loading it. In a way, you turn PostgreSQL into a CSV parser.

Then you can select from that foreign table like from a normal table and for example insert parts of it into a proper PostgreSQL table.